# How to integrate angular 8 with gradle?

Tags: angular, gradle, build.gradle, angular9

I want to integrate angular and gradle,
Is there any way to integrate them so that i can create jar file angular using gradle?
I need to integrate angular with gradle to create jar file.How to manage angular plugins in build.gradle?

Comment: how do you expect to use your Angular jar after it is created?

Comment: What do you intend to achieve by integrating angular with gradle?